# Protect Browser localstorage with WebAuthn

Tags: javascript, webcrypto-api, webauthn

The idea is to use public/private key cryptography to store encrypted data that only a user  with biometric login can access it.

I 'm successfully using WebAuthn and [this library](https://github.com/lbuchs/WebAuthn/) to login and I store the credential ID and a public key. Now, as I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59837620/webauthn-for-encryption), I can't use this to encrypt data because I can't have the WebAuthn API decrypt it, its only used for authentication.

The question is, can I protect local browser storage with WebAuthn? If so, I could use `window.crypto.subtle.generateKey` to generate a RSA key, store the private locally and protect it with WebAuthn, then reuse it when necessary.

Best,

Comment: No, I don't believe that is possible.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing would be to use the [PRF extension](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#prf-extension) that's in the draft of WebAuthn level three. However, it is not yet supported in any browser nor by any platform authenticator I'm afraid. (Although many FIDO2 security keys support the underlying `hmac-secret` extension to CTAP2.)